# Why does Pybricks on ev3dev have slow performance compared to EV3-G?

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, ev3dev, pybricks

I got MINDSTORMS EV3 for my son and me. We installed Python (ev3dev) and ii seems to be running very slowly. I tried setting up the classic LEGO ev3g (block code), and that seems to run fine.

Are we doing something wrong or is Python very slow on MINDSTORMS?

Please help!

Example:

Simple program - display count and loop 100 times

Python: ~1.5s

ev3g: ~0.15s

Edit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env pybricks-micropython

from pybricks.hubs import EV3Brick
from pybricks.tools import wait, StopWatch
    
ev3 = EV3Brick()
ev3.speaker.beep()
timer = StopWatch()
    
for x in range(0, 100):
    ev3.screen.print(str(x) + ':' + str(timer.time()))
  
wait(5000)
```

This on the screen the last line displayed is
99:1113

this takes just over ~ 1.1s to loop 100 times

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE.  Can you post the python source code?

Comment: @chicks sorry for the delay. I have added the code for the python end. nothing fancy. Any idea why it is so slow?

Comment: We cannot post our answer at the moment, we are voting to reopen the question so that it can be answered. And this is actually the comments section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing text in `pybricks-micropython` on ev3dev has known performance issues, so we don't recommend doing that in a loop. The trade off is that, unlike ev3-g, you can also print in other languages that don't use Latin scripts like Chinese and Russian. Most other things should run much faster.